# JavaFX Animation Timer class is not capping at 60 fps

Tags: java, javafx

So I have been making a game with JavaFX and I wanted to keep the fps at 60 always. However although normally the Animation Timer class in JavaFX caps fps at 60, in my case it isn't. I have tried quite a few different solutions to this, which are shown in the lines:

```
    System.setProperty("quantum.multithreading", "false");
    System.setProperty("javafx.animation.fullspeed", "true");
    System.setProperty("javafx.animation.pulse", "60");
    System.setProperty("javafx.animation.framerate", "60");
```

However, these solutions are not working. I did a bit more error checking and think that my error is caused by the screen refresh rate changing the capped fps in JavaFX, i.e. When screen refresh rate is 60Hz the fps is 60fps, but when screen refresh rate is 48Hz the fps is 48fps. I was wondering how I would stop the fps changing based on the screen refresh rate and keep it capped at a constant 60fps. Here is my code below, any help would be appreciated:

```
package battlegame;

import java.io.IOException;

import battlegame.graphics.Assets;
import battlegame.input.KeyboardController;
import battlegame.world.World;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.LongProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleLongProperty;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Game extends Application{

    public static int screenWidth = 960;
    public static int screenHeight = 540;

     private final long[] frameTimes = new long[100];
     private int frameTimeIndex = 0 ;
     private boolean arrayFilled = false ;

    private Canvas canvas;
    private boolean upTyped = true;
    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private Group group;
    private GraphicsContext g;
    private final LongProperty lastUpdateTime = new SimpleLongProperty(0);
    private static World currentWorld;
    private static KeyboardController keyController;

    public Game() {
        keyController = new KeyboardController();
    }

    public void begin(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void initialise() throws IOException {
        canvas = new Canvas(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        group = new Group(canvas);
        scene = new Scene(group);
        g = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        Assets.init();
        currentWorld = new World("/testlvl.txt");
        currentWorld.init();

        System.setProperty("quantum.multithreading", "false");
        System.setProperty("javafx.animation.fullspeed", "true");
        System.setProperty("javafx.animation.pulse", "60");
        System.setProperty("javafx.animation.framerate", "60");

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)throws Exception {
        initialise();

        final AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long timestamp) {
                long oldFrameTime = frameTimes[frameTimeIndex] ;
                frameTimes[frameTimeIndex] = timestamp ;
                frameTimeIndex = (frameTimeIndex + 1) % frameTimes.length ;
                if (frameTimeIndex == 0) {
                    arrayFilled = true ;
                }
                if (arrayFilled) {
                    long elapsedNanos = timestamp - oldFrameTime ;
                    long elapsedNanosPerFrame = elapsedNanos / frameTimes.length ;
                    double frameRate = 1_000_000_000.0 / elapsedNanosPerFrame ;
                    System.out.println(frameRate);
                }

                if (lastUpdateTime.get() > 0) {
                    tick();
                    render();
                }
                lastUpdateTime.set(timestamp);
            }
        };
        stage = primaryStage;
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(Game.class.getResourceAsStream("/GameIcon.png")));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(true);
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
            timer.stop();
        });
        stage.show();
        scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (key) -> {
              if(upTyped && (key.getCode() == KeyCode.W || key.getCode() == KeyCode.UP || key.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE)) {
                  keyController.up = true;
                  upTyped = false;
              }
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.A || key.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
                  keyController.left = true;
              }
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.S || key.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                  keyController.down = true;
              }
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.D || key.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
                  keyController.right = true;
              }
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.Z || key.getCode() == KeyCode.O || key.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                  keyController.select = true;
              }
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.P || key.getCode() == KeyCode.X) {
                  keyController.action = true;
              }

        });
        /*scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, (key) -> {
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.W || key.getCode() == KeyCode.UP || key.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
                  keyController.up = true;
                  System.out.println("YoIghtL/Kkjkjas");
              }
        });*/

        scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, (key) -> {
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.W || key.getCode() == KeyCode.UP || key.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
                  keyController.up = false;
                  upTyped = true;
              }
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.A || key.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
                  keyController.left = false;
              }
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.S || key.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                  keyController.down = false;
              }
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.D || key.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
                  keyController.right = false;
              }
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.Z || key.getCode() == KeyCode.O || key.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                  keyController.select = false;
              }
              if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.P || key.getCode() == KeyCode.X) {
                  keyController.action = false;
              }     });



        timer.start();   
    }


    public void tick() {
        currentWorld.tick();
        keyController.tick();
    }

    public void render() {
        g.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        currentWorld.render(g);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch();
    }

    public static KeyboardController getKeyController(){
        return keyController;
    }

    public static World getCurrentWorld() {
        return currentWorld;
    }



    }
```

Comment: This is the GitHub repository of the game: https://github.com/JacobInwald/BattleGame. I will keep it public for a few days, but will have to make it private again soon.

Comment: wich OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and the IDE I am using is eclipse

Comment: I am not an expert on the game loop, but I would suggest you read about it more. I would suggest that you try to achieve a rate of 40 something FPS. Why do you need it at 60? There are a lot of factors that come into play.

Comment: Also, how is the key handling working out? I would not handle my key events in this manner.

Comment: The key handling is very good and efficient and it needs to run at 60fps as I have calculated all my physics like gravity in the game to work at 60fps. If it runs faster or slower, the player will either move slower and gravity will be weaker or the player will go faster and gravity will be stronger.

Comment: https://carlfx.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/javafx-2-gametutorial-part-1/

Comment: https://dewitters.com/dewitters-gameloop/

Comment: @Sedrick so you're recommending using a Timeline class instead of an Animation Timer right? That's what this tutorial is using. I'll give it a go and see if I get the same issue. Thank you

Comment: Yes this did fix the issue of differing frame rate based on screen refresh rate, thank you!

Comment: @JacobInwald there are at least 5 programmers that I turn to when trying to learn things related to JavaFX. The guy who did the tutorial in the first link is one of these people.

Comment: @Sedrick I will keep this in mind when I am stuck on future problems in JavaFX, thanks a million.

Comment: You're setting those system properties in the `initialize()` method which you call from the `start(Stage)` method. By that time the JavaFX runtime has been initialized and most likely already read the system properties and cached the results—meaning you setting them has no effect. Try passing those properties on the command line or at least set them before the JavaFX runtime is launched. If you choose the latter approach, the main method would probably work but only if your main class is not also your `Application` subclass.